# Python inverse exponential function with two variables

Tags: python, math

I have a simple function:

```
def f(x,y):
   return y * 2 ** x
```

, where `x` can be an integer in `[0,14]`, `y` can be an integer in `[0, 255]`.

I'm trying to write a python function that find the `(x, y)` pair in the given interval above, for any values of `f(x, y)` in `[0, 200000]` range.

I'm interested in a solution other than brute force, if any.

The brute force version below:

```
def inverse_f(value, delta):
    results = []
    for x in range(0, 10):
        for y in range(0, 255):
            candidate = 2 ** x * y
            if value - delta <= candidate <= value + delta:
                results.append((x, y, candidate))
    return results

>>> inverse_f(10, 1)
>>> [(0, 9, 9), (0, 10, 10), (0, 11, 11), (1, 5, 10)]

>>> inverse_f(10, 0)
>>> [(0, 10, 10), (1, 5, 10)]
```

Comment: There's not a unique solution. Given an output z, do you want any (x,y) pair such that f(x,y)=z? There can be infinitely many such pairs.

Comment: Given a particular value of `f(x,y)` and a given `c` there are infinitely many pairs `(x, y)` that give that particular value. How are we to choose the pair `(x, y)`? In other words, there is no inverse function. Things change a bit if `x` and `y` are required to be integers--is that the case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah the values are integers. Let me edit the question.
It is about programming. I'd like to write a python function that for a given value of `f(x,y)` is giving me an `x` and an `y`.

Comment: It would only be about programming if you knew the algorithm, but had trouble translating it into code. Right now, you have neither.

Comment: So you claim that discussing ways to create an algorithm for a given situation is not in the scope of SO?

Comment: Algorithm questions can be on-topic here. But you would need to state that algorithms are the topic of your question. You also would need to show some work of your own, just as in other types of questions. You would also need to give all the problem requirements in sufficient detail. Your question was lacking in all those areas. If you improve your question in those areas I will vote to reopen the question. --Your last edit did improve your question, but you still are not showing much work of your own.

Comment: Alright, thanks Rory. I added the brute force version that is working for me as is. I'm not interested in any algorithm optimisation for now, but would be nice if somebody can find something better than the brute force. Thanks.

Comment: Based on your edits, I have voted to reopen this question. I also have an answer and will post it if allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ignoring the constant c, since if you know it, and are given a result, just divide c out. Then proceed as if c didn't exist and f(x,y) = 2^x * y

There can be multiple solutions for a given value.  For example, if x=7 and y=5, you get the same result as if x=6 and y=10.  So we set some policy for choosing a unique inverse.

The easiest appears to be: just count the zeros from the right end. That tells you x. The bunch of bits following the zeros, up to the most significant set bit, when looking right to left, tells you y.

```
  1011100000    given result
      100000    x=5 
* 10111         y=23
```

Alternatively, the policy could be to make y as large as possible. Find the most-significant '1', starting from the left, take that and seven more bits to the right of it.  Then see how many bits remain, to get x

```
  1011100000    given result
  ^             most sig non-zero bit is here
  10111000      take eight bits for y=184
*        100    this times y is result; conclude x=2
```

My brain isn't coming up with a super-slick way to do this; good ol' fashioned bit shifting and keeping count in a 'for' loop is what I'd write. If you are writing at the machine code level, your CPU may have bit position instructions to make this quick.